# display the weight of balls in ascending order

Tags: java

Now the information is displayed in order (by ball number) How can I display the weight of the balls in ascending order?

```
public class WorkWithBall {
public static double WeightBall(){
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(10)/2.5+1;
}

public class WorkWithBasket {
public static Basket fillBasket(Basket basket){
    for(int i =0; i < basket.getVolume(); i++){
        Ball temp = new Ball(Color.getRandomColor(),WorkWithBall.WeightBall());
        basket.addBall(temp);
    }
    return basket;
}
public static void InfoOut (Basket basket){
    for (int i = 0; i < basket.getBasket().length; i++){
        System.out.println("Ball #" + (i+1) + " with color - " + basket.getBasket()[i].getColor()+
                " weight - " + basket.getBasket()[i].getWeight());
    }
}
```

[image: information output]

Comment: If you can use lists instead of arrays, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396970/sort-a-list-that-contains-a-custom-class).

Comment: Could you please post the code of `class Basket`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8, get a stream from the balls array. Sort by weight, as follows:

```
Stream.of(basket.getBasket()).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Ball::getWeight)).forEach(ball -> {
            System.out.println(ball.getColor() + " " + ball.getWeight());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Stream` and `sorted()` like

```java
public static void InfoOut (Basket basket){
    Arrays.stream(basket.getBasket()).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Ball::getWeight)).forEach((Ball ball) -> {
        System.out.println("Ball #" + (i+1) + " with color - " + basket.getBasket()[i].getColor()+ " weight - " + basket.getBasket()[i].getWeight());
    })
}
```

Also please note that your print should be placed in `toString` method of `Ball` overriden from `Object` class.
And you might simplify the stream like

```java
Arrays.stream(basket.getBasket()).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Ball::getWeight)).forEach(System.out::println);
```